# xdescribe,xit says 'Unknown identifier 'xdescribe'/'xit' respectively

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

I tried to disable describe suite block by writing xdescribe and jasmine shows me warning 'unknown identifier xdescribe' same for 'xit', pls help!!

```
describe("Pending specs", function () { 

    xit("can be declared 'xit'", function () { 
        expect(true).toBe(false); 
    }); 

    it("can be declared with 'it' but without a function"); 

    it("can be declared by calling 'pending' in the spec body", function () { 
        expect(true).toBe(false); pending(); }); 
    }); 

});
```

// my config.js

```
exports.config = { 
    //seleniumAddress: 'localhost: 4444 / wd / hub';, 
    specs: ['nestedDescribe.js'] 
};
```

Comment: Please show your  package.json and protractor conf.js

Comment: @yong:- '
describe("Pending specs", function() {

 xit("can be declared 'xit'", function() {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
 });

 it("can be declared with 'it' but without a function");

 it("can be declared by calling 'pending' in the spec body", function() {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
  pending();
 });
});'  and my config.js is:- exports.config = {
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['nestedDescribe.js']
};

Comment: Please update code in your question, rather than in comment.  I move code in above comment in question, but the second `it` seems not correct and there is no `xdescribe` in your code. Please update the code if they are not correct.